# BigQuery GCP Regression Model issues

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, regression

I am working on a lab to build a regression model in BigQuery on GCP. I followed the steps almost exactly, but the last query I run fails. Here's what I did.

1. In BigQuery, I clicked "Create dataset" to create a dataset with the default options.
2. I created a table and uploaded a CSV file that I downloaded of tick data of stock prices. The table included the columns: Time (this is just the tick number), Price, and Volume. I kept all the default options, but I checked off the "Auto detect" option.
3. I ran the following query and saved it to a data table:

   ```
   WITH
     raw AS (
     SELECT
       Time,
       Price,
       LAG(Price, 1) OVER(ORDER BY Time) AS min_1_Price,
       LAG(Price, 2) OVER(ORDER BY Time) AS min_2_Price,
       LAG(Price, 3) OVER(ORDER BY Time) AS min_3_Price,
       LAG(Price, 4) OVER(ORDER BY Time) AS min_4_Price
     FROM
       `dataset.table`
     ORDER BY
       Time DESC ),
     raw_plus_trend AS (
     SELECT
       Time,
       Price,
       min_1_Price,
       IF (min_1_Price - min_2_Price > 0, 1, -1) AS min_1_trend,
       IF (min_2_Price - min_3_Price > 0, 1, -1) AS min_2_trend,
       IF (min_3_Price - min_4_Price > 0, 1, -1) AS min_3_trend
     FROM
       raw ),
     ml_data AS (
     SELECT
       Time,
       Price,
       min_1_Price AS day_prev_Price,
       IF (min_1_trend + min_2_trend + min_3_trend > 0, 1, -1) AS trend_3_day
     FROM
       raw_plus_trend )
   SELECT
     *
   FROM
     ml_data
   ```
4. I created a regression model by running this query:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `dataset.model`
   OPTIONS
     ( model_type='linear_reg',
       input_label_cols=['Price'],
       data_split_method='seq',
       data_split_eval_fraction=0.3,
       data_split_col='Time') AS
   SELECT
     Time,
     Price,
     day_prev_Price,
     trend_3_day
   FROM
     `dataset.model_data`
   ```
5. This is where I failed. I ran this query to make the predictions, but it didn't produce anything. I just used 130000 as my time, since the ticks in my table only went up to 124256.

   ```
   SELECT
     *
   FROM
     ml.PREDICT(MODEL `dataset.model`,
       (
       SELECT
         *
       FROM
         `dataset.model_data`
       WHERE
         Time >= 130000) )
   ```

What is going wrong here? I also tried the same query at the end with Time >= 124256 and it only produced one row of results, which just turned out to be the same price in the original table.

Comment: Your request may not respect the schema. Go to the BigQuery UI, select your model, and click on schema. Can you paste the result in your question? Same thing for the dataset.model_data table. Thanks

Comment: The model schema has predicted_Price under labels, and day_prev_Price and trend_3_day under features. The model data table has Time, Price, day_prev_Price, and trend_3_day. Should they be the same?

Comment: Yes, try with only the day_prev_price and trend_3_day in your select

Comment: Which select are you talking about? The one in the last query?

Comment: Yes, in the step 5, select only the input column.